# How to add table to table?

Tags: lua

I want to add table 'mm' to table 'fmenu.pages' but it doesnt work at all. Error: attempt to index a nil value (field 'main2'). Its about last line. Code:

```
local fmenu = {
    selected_button = 0,
    menu = {
        font = 1,
    },
    pages = {
        ["main"] = {
            name = "name",
            id = 1,
            btns = {
                {name = "name I",  id = 1}
            }
        }
    }
}

local mm = {
    ["main2"] = {
        name = "name2",
        id = 2,
        btns = {
            {name = "name I",  id = 1},
            {name = "name II",  id = 2}
        }
    }
}

table.insert(fmenu.pages, mm)
print(fmenu.pages["main2"].name)
```

Comment: Try `fmenu.pages.main2 = mm.main2` (if you have additional pages: main3, main4,... inside `mm`, then you have to write for-loop to add them one-by-one)

Comment: You saved my another 3-4 hours haha Thank you :)

Comment: `table.insert(fmenu.pages, mm)` is equivalent to `fmenu.pages[1]=mm`, which is not what you want.

Comment: There is other way to do this better?

Answer (score 1):

How about using `table.merge` from [`lua-stdlib`](https://github.com/lua-stdlib/lua-stdlib)?

```
local table = require"std.table"

local fmenu = {
    selected_button = 0,
    menu = {
        font = 1,
    },
    pages = {
        ["main"] = {
            name = "name",
            id = 1,
            btns = {
                {name = "name I",  id = 1}
            }
        }
    }
}

local mm = {
    ["main2"] = {
        name = "name2",
        id = 2,
        btns = {
            {name = "name I",  id = 1},
            {name = "name II",  id = 2}
        }
    }
}

table.merge(fmenu.pages, mm)
print(fmenu.pages["main2"].name)
```